# Is it possible to switch between video tracks in HTML5 MSE?

Tags: javascript, html, video, streaming, media-source

I'm using HTML5 [Media source extensions (MSE)](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/) to stream a video using [DASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP). I created my media segments using [MP4Box](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/dash/) from a MP4 file with two video tracks in it. So what I have is a single initialisation segment with `moov->sidx` boxes and multiple media-segments `moof->mdat` containing both video tracks. If I push them to the [`sourceBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource/addSourceBuffer) with `appendBuffer` function, MSE decodes and shows only the first video track (I assume that the data from the second video track is just discarded).

Here are the relevant parts from my code:

```
sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(stats.mimeType); // mime type: video/mp4
...
// after downloading mediasegment append its contents 'data' to sourceBuffer
sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(new Uint8Array(data));
```

So my question is, is it possible to control the sourceBuffer in such a way that the client can select which track to decode? I suppose that splitting the video tracks to different adaptation sets (creating separate mp4 files with a single video track in each one) could be a solution but I'm not interested in this approach.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I found a way how to do this. Using [videoTracks](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-media-videotracks) attribute we can access the video tracks and change its [selected](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-videotrack-selected) attribute. So it was pretty simple to do.

Here is an example how to toggle the tracks after third segment was downloaded:

```
if(segmentCnt==3 && sourceBuffer.videoTracks.length == 2)
{
    console.log('tracks cnt: ' + sourceBuffer.videoTracks.length);
    for(var i=0; i<sourceBuffer.videoTracks.length; i=i+1) {
        var trackID = sourceBuffer.videoTracks[i].id;
        var trackSelected = sourceBuffer.videoTracks[i].selected;
        console.log('trackID: ' + trackID + ' selected: ' + trackSelected);
        sourceBuffer.videoTracks[i].selected = !trackSelected;
    }
}
```